# How do I create an iCal-type .ics file that can be downloaded by other users?

Tags: macos, calendar, icalendar

I want to create an iCal Calendar that can be downloaded from my website to the users Calendar program or imported to Google Calendar. What I want to know is if I do a direct Export from iCal on Mac OS X is that the file that I upload to my server? Any catches or caveats I should be aware of? Or is there a better way?

Answer (score 14):

That will work just fine. You can export an entire calendar with `File` > `Export…`, or individual events by dragging them to the Finder.

iCalendar (`.ics`) files are human-readable, so you can always pop it open in a text editor to make sure no private events made it in there. They consist of nested sections with start with `BEGIN:` and end with `END:`. You'll mostly find `VEVENT` sections (each of which represents an event) and `VTIMEZONE` sections, each of which represents a time zone that's referenced from one or more events.

Comment: Dragging event for `.ics`, *so* not discoverable! Thanks.

Comment: Confirmed: dragging individual calendar events from Outlook for Mac 2011 creates an .ics file with the name of the event on the desktop. I had looked for an export feature on the context menu, but there isn't one.

Answer (score 12):

Simple use this great free online tool:

https://pratie.tomodea.dev/lab/icalendar/default.asp

Comment: broken link `500 - Internal server error.
There is a problem with the resource you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed.`

Comment: Updated link:  https://pratie.tomodea.dev/lab/icalendar/default.asp

Answer (score 8):

There is also this tool you can use. It supports multi-events .ics file creation.
It also supports timezone as well.

https://ical.marudot.com

Comment: This one works well. Several of the other ones are buggy (including http://www.pratie.com/lab/icalendar).

Answer (score 1):

I find the following link quite useful

http://blog.hubspot.com/marketing/calendar-invites-ical-outlook-google