# Is it possible for a website to set an alarm on a user's iPhone?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ios, alarms

I have limited HTML, CSS and Javascript experience.

However, I am wondering if it is possible to code a simple website that can set an alarm on whatever device the user is accessing the website on by tapping/clicking a button.

A real world example of the scenario could sound like this: I am a user using Safari on my iPhone. I tap a button on the site I am visiting that reads "Set Alarm for 9:36 AM". My iPhone switches out of Safari and into the native alarm app's "Add Alarm" function with 9:36 AM as the default value.

Thanks.

Comment: Actually, it is possible. Sort of. Calendar reminders works just as good, and they can be added with just two clicks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're okay with calendar events, you could just create an ical file ([How do I create an iCal-type .ics file that can be downloaded by other users?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1490634/how-do-i-create-an-ical-type-ics-file-that-can-be-downloaded-by-other-users)) and set up a link there (`<a href="event.ical">Set alarm</a>`). The ical file can then be set to play a signal (reminder). When the user clicks the link on his/her iDevice/Mac, iCal will open and the user will just have to tap save and it's done.

Actually, I think vCalendar (The same? .ics, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICalendar) will work on all devices.

You should also checkout url protocols to open other apps.

Good luck!

Comment: I looked up some url protocols for native iPhone apps. Apparently there is no protocol for the Clock app, but there is one for the Reminders app. However, I can't seem to find a way to add custom parameters such as setting a date and time. The protocol only opens the app.

Comment: I'm saving the calendar app as a last resort because it wouldn't be optimal for this situation, especially if the user specified a recurring event. Although calendar reminders support recurring events, they would also print the event all over the calendar which could be annoying for a user who sets a daily reminder.